# Regex PHP: Phone number international format, +

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Users should enter a phone number in international format, it should always start with a +, and without any special chars, so for example +3162503277.

I thought this simple regex would do it, but somehow I must be missing something, because it doesn't accept the phone number:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\+?[0-9]{6}$/i', $phone)) 
    fail("Invalid phone number");
```

What should be the way to check if the number starts with a + and further only contains numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appending `?` after `\+` makes `+` optional.

`[0-9]{6}$` match only 6 digits. To match more digits, you have to use `+` isntead of `{6}`.
If you want 6 or more digits, use `{6,}`.

Try following:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\+\d+$/', $phone)) 
    fail("Invalid phone number");
```

Comment: You're completely correct, but I'd like to help clarify one point.  `{6}$` means six digits with nothing after.  If "$" was missing, his regex would still match 316250